# Signal invertor for power switch using 3.5mm audio jack switch

Tags: switches, inverter

I have a 3.5mm audio jack with a switch build in. When you plug a jack in the switch opens. I would love to use this build in switch as a power on switch for a small device so when i plug in a head phone jack it closes a circuit and powers on the device. I don't know how to use the open circuit of the audio jack to close a power circuit.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Is the switch in the jack plug or the jack socket?

Comment: Which configuration of switched jack socket is it? There are many. Please post the switch type schematic. Also what are you plugging in? Is it really a two channel headphone jack or a single channel device.

Comment: BTW.. your title is miss-leading... this has little to do a signal invertor.

Comment: Its a simple mono 3.5mm audio jack with an extra part that is pushed apart breaking the circuit when a head phone jack is inserted. Maybe i used the wrong word but i wanted to invert the signal so low would be high and high would be low.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, i just needed to use an NPN transistor.
[image]

Comment: Your load will then not see GND but GND+Vce,sat. If that's good enough for your application then fine! If not, then you may want to consider a high side switch instead - implementable with a PNP for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a pull-up resistor to Vcc and a connection to GND and you're set. Use the ENABLE signal (active high) for triggering power-up as needed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD50YCm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or you could also use the jack switch to turn ON a PNP BJT and switch a load (or a relay if you want to switch higher voltages):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNzzx6.png)</sup>

Comment: Maybe i am just being thick but how would the pull-up resistor work? Not sure what the Enable Pin means in this example. What would a full diagram look like if you were using a 3V battery the audio jack and the pull up resistor for example.

Comment: The above circuit is broken.  I'll try to correct it later if the person who posted this answer doesn't get to it first.

Comment: Im glad its not just me

Comment: Yes, there's an error in the second schematic. I can't correct it now, I'll do it when I'm in front of a PC. Thanks, @DwayneReid !